# OpenCV putText does not work after flipping the image

Tags: python, numpy, opencv

I'd like to grab images from the camera and flip them left/right so that the view performs like a mirror. However, I also like to add some text to the view, but it turns out that after flipping the image using `np.fliplr(frame)`, `cv.putText` does no longer work.

Here is my minimal example using `python 3.5.2`:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
import platform

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("python version:", platform.python_version())
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
    while(True):
        # Capture frame-by-frame
        ret, frame = cap.read()

        cv2.putText(frame,'Hello World : Before flip',(100, 100), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 1,(255,255,255),2,cv2.LINE_AA)
        frame = np.fliplr(frame)
        cv2.putText(frame,'Hello World : After flip',(100, 200), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 1,(255,255,255),2,cv2.LINE_AA)

        # Process the keys
        key = cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF
        if key == ord('q'):
            print("quit")
            break
        # show the images
        cv2.imshow('frame',frame)

    cap.release()
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Resulting frame w/ flip:
[image]

Resulting frame w/o flip:
[image]

Comment: Actually, in some versions of OpenCV it not only doesn't work, it actually throws an exception. Given that the docs of [`np.fliplr`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.2/reference/generated/numpy.fliplr.html) say it's an O(1) operation, I guess it changes the metadata of the array in a way that OpenCV's python bindings don't support. | Seems like making a copy of the flipped array and using that works fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suspect it's due to `cv2.putText` is not compatible with `np.array` which is the return value of `np.fliplr(frame)`. I suggest that you use `frame = cv2.flip(frame, 1)` instead.

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
import platform

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("python version:", platform.python_version())
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
    while(True):
        # Capture frame-by-frame
        ret, frame = cap.read()

        cv2.putText(frame,'Hello World : Before flip',(100, 100), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 1,(255,255,255),2,cv2.LINE_AA)
        frame = cv2.flip(frame, 1)
        cv2.putText(frame,'Hello World : After flip',(100, 200), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 1,(255,255,255),2,cv2.LINE_AA)

        # Process the keys
        key = cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF
        if key == ord('q'):
            print("quit")
            break
        # show the images
        cv2.imshow('frame',frame)

    cap.release()
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: ok, this seems to work but I noticed a strange behavior: Both texts are displayed non-mirrored. How does this work? I assume the first text to be mirrored because it is inserted before the flipping. However, `frame = np.fliplr(frame).copy()` has the desired behaviour!

Comment: I just tested the code, the text before the flip is indeed mirrored. Isn't this your expected behavior? https://imgur.com/a/oSNk8eW

Comment: Everything is fine. I am just wondering that with your solution, the text 'Hello World : Before flip' is not mirrored.

Answer (score -1):

Just flip the frame before putting the text:

```
frame = cv2.flip(frame, 1)
cv2.putText(...)
```